Passivisation of the content clause
When passives are formed by promoting the subject of the content clause to the subject of the main clause and converting the content clause into a non-finite clause with the to-infinitive, how do we match the tense as per the tense in my question?
For example,
They report that she came back -> She is reported to have come back.
Question:
In the infinitive tenses, the corresponding tenses for both present tense and simple future are "to + bare infinitive". Given that, how do we write example 2?


They say that he cheats. → He is said to cheat.

They say that he will cheat -> ?




He is said to be going to cheat.

Assuming generic 'they', as (1) implies, (2) -> 'It is said that he will cheat.'  Stuart's 'He is said to be going to cheat.' is subtly different, less open to being conditional.

I’m voting to close this question because "to come back" and (in this use) "to cheat" are intransitive verbs that cannot form a passive.

I know that they are intransitive. And so are come, die etc. They say that he cheats. → He is said to cheat.
They think that I am dying. → I am thought to be dying.
They report that she came back / has come back. → She is reported to have come back.

@Greybeard — say is a transitive verb, and that is the verb being put into passive form here.

@TinfoilHat - the question is specifically about the content clause, not about the [reporting] verb in the main clause: that would be too easy. "It was said that..."

@A_Mendes If you know the verbs in the content clause are intransitive, you must know that they cannot be passivised.

@Greybeard — Where do you see OP asking to make passive the verb in the content clause? (And, in any case, cheat can be a transitive verb.)

@TinfoilHat: in the title "Passivisation of the content clause" (And, "Yes, I have noted in my comment that "cheat" can be transitive, but is not in the present context.")

It is said that he will cheat, but that is awful. Maligning someone and hiding begind nameless accusers.

@YosefBaskin Your comment is funny. And it is preposterous when more prolific writers including the one who has given the correct answer never found any problem with that. It is perfectly proper and is taken from a site that the Google search engine puts on its first page ALWAYS.

Quote: "They say (that) he cheats.
It is possible to convert this to a passive by promoting the content clause to subject; in this case, however, the clause typically does not change its position in the sentence, and an expletive it takes the normal subject position:
It is said that he cheats."

You could use the idiomatic be going in the infinitival, though in this situation it is rare and comes off a little awkwardly.

Trump is said to be going to work the “fry cooker” at the fast-food
restaurant. His campaign has not revealed which location in the city
he'll visit. (NBC Philadelphia)

The best solution is simply to rephrase using expect.

They say that he will cheat -> He is (widely) expected to cheat.


This is the sensible workaround. But I'm not sure OP is open to such; enquirers often want 'the precise rules [here, of transformation]'. Even when they're almost never used (or even known) by native speakers. And assuming they really exist.

I agree with the statement but it is not parallel to the question

With most reporting verbs that report an event with a future aspect, you need to use this passive pattern:

it + passive reporting verb + that-clause

So:

Active: They say that he will cheat.
Passive: It is said that he will cheat.

